# Bootstrap or JQuery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

i'm beginning a phonegap application, but i'm hesitating about which CSS and JS framework i'll use : **Bootstrap from twitter** which give pretty render but uses LESS or **Jquery mobile** which is very easy to implement.
what do you think about them ?
thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap with normal CSS:

http://www.initializr.com/

Besides, it is better suited for starting to play with responsive design.

Comment: thank you ! Should i choose "mobile-first responsive" or "responsive bootstrap 2.1.0" ?

Comment: I tried Responsive Bootstrap with good results. When you download the file, Index.html will contain links to responsive CSS, bootstrap CSS, etc. Just tweak them to your liking. HTML5Boileplate is a really good starting place for your HTML, with all the community knowledge. BTW, nothing stops you from combining Bootstrap and jQuery Mobile and/or other frameworks. Everything depends so much on your requirements, really.

Answer (score 7):

**Bootstrap**

- Looks nicer by default and has a better range of themes that aren't just alternate colour-schemes.
- More responsive in both layout **and** performance.
- You can [select only the components that you'll need](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html), perhaps excluding the JS features if you're looking for a lightweight build focussed on layout and design.

**jQuery Mobile**

- Good for rapid prototyping if you aren't overly-concerned about performance nor the iOS-like appearance and behaviour
- jQuery Mobile's [Listview](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/listviews/) will
  save you a lot of timeif you're building a mobile companian to an online shop or  something else with lots of lists or sub-navigation.

There is a mobile framework comparison that might be useful to give you an idea of the best option for your needs: http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/